# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pathlib' has no attribute 'Path' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simple program using the pathlib directory, but every time I try to run it I get this error. I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling Path.py and pathlib itself. Nothing seems to work.

```
import pathlib


path = pathlib.Path('ecommerce')
print(path.exists())
```

Here's the code if anybody needs it, but as I said, I just wanted to try out this module and the program itself doesn't do anything.

Also, here's the entire log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Programming\Python\pathlib.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Programming\Python\pathlib.py", line 4, in <module>
    path = pathlib.Path('ecommerce')
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pathlib' has no attribute 'Path' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: You named one of your own files `pathlib.py`, which means that gets imported instead of the stdlib `pathlib`. Rename your file.

Answer (score 1):

Python is being confused about what pathlib you're talking about.

Don't name your own program `pathlib`, or any other module name in the standard library for that matter.

This also stands even if you're not directly importing the module - if some other module would attempt to import pathlib, there'd be the same conflict.

Comment: Thanks lol, should have seen that coming.